# How can I use click_log to control the logging level in a python project with multiple modules?

Tags: python, logging, command-line-interface

I have a Python cli project which uses [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) and [click-log](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-log). My project has two modules `cli.py` and `doit.py`.

In the main module `cli.py` I use

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
click_log.basic_config(log)
```

as suggest in the click_log documentation and the logging in this module is perfectly controllable via the `--verbosity` option on the command line.

In the other module `doit.py`  I instantiate the logger as is best practice with

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This however results to the log level *in the `doit` module* always being set to `WARNING` independent of the command line option.

How can I use click_log in a way that it applies to the secondary module `doit.py` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

I assign `doit`'s logger variable in the main `cli.py` like this:

```
# --- Excerpt from cli.py ---
.
.
.
import doit

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
doit.log = log
click_log.basic_config(log)
.
.
.
```

I'm not too happy with this solution. - It looks pretty convoluted to set the logger variables to the same object in `cli.py`, but that's the best I could come up with using click_log.
This appear to me as not very